# cannot open a connection to the report server database

Tags: reporting-services, report

when i execute http://localhost//reportserver this gives me  following error..

The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. The log on failed. (rsReportServerDatabaseLogonFailed)

Answer (score 5):

That is a common error message if it is the first time you are using SSRS. If so, then you will need to enable Named Pipes. Here is how:

- Open the SQL Server Configuration Management tool.
- Click "SQL ServerNetwork Configuration"
- Click "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER"
- Make sure both the **TCP/IP** and **Named Pipes** protocols are enabled. (To enable
  a protocol, right-click on the protocol and click "Enable")

Comment: You do not need to enable Token Ring unless you are still on a Token Ring network, ie you are on 1980s IBM network technology.

Answer (score 1):

Run the configuration tool again, ensure the database section is configured appropriately and actually works.

Answer (score 0):

check the connection string - is it using a trusted connection? if so, it will be connecting as the same user that your web application is.

either give the user access to the specific database, or change the connection string to a sql server user account.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where the name of my system had changed since I had installed SSRS. I opened Reporting Services Config Manager and in the Database section, set the SQL Server Name to `(local)`.

[image: SSRS Config Manager with SQL Server Name set to (local)]

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is someone updated password for user that run services for reporting service. I use these steps:

```
 1. Open reporting service configuration manager
 2. Load your server
 3. Click database tab
 4. Click change credential
 5. Click next, load your authentication (in my case, I choose service authentication, not changed from before)
 6. Click next until finish
 7. Reload your site, then voila
 8. Finish
```

Comment: I think it's same with kyzen, just explain the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Password for the sql user used in report server configuration manager was expired. Post changing, it worked.

Note: Reports were working fine, but suddenly it stopped.